# Like Button, send button displays random pictures

Tags: facebook-like

How do I specify the product image that I want the send button to display.  I would like it to display the product on the product page but it seems to just pick up random images from the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add some `og:tags` to your page.  Please read the [Open Graph Protocol Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) for details on the different tags and what they mean.  
A quick example :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

Once you have placed the correct `og:tags` and set their values, you can use the [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see how facebook views your URL.